# Elasticsearch read only user

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to add a read only user to my cluster, my app prefixes all its indexes with `myapp_`.

Following https://www.elastic.co/blog/user-impersonation-with-x-pack-integrating-third-party-auth-with-kibana (what a strange title for the only actually usable blog post on this...) I have first added a role with

```
curl -XPOST '$ELASTIC_URL:9200/_xpack/security/role/name_of_readonly_role' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d'{"indices":[{"names":"myapp_*","privileges":["read"]}]}'
```

and then added it to a user:

```
curl -XPOST $ELASTIC_URL:9200/_xpack/security/user/name_of_user \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d'{"roles":["name_of_readonly_role"],"password":"some_password"}'
```

but when opening `$ELASTIC_URL:9200` I got

```
action [cluster:monitor/main] is unauthorized for user
```

what's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a complete dearth of examples for this as far as I can see, to fix this problem the role command needs to be re-run with `-d'{"cluster":["monitor"], "indices":[{"names":"myapp_*","privileges":["read"]}]}'` (same curl command works for creating or updating roles). This seems to leak the name of all indexes but not much else aside from their names and I was fine with that. And even that seems to be not enough for some apps like the ElasticSearch Head brower extension, I needed to add the index level monitor privilege as well: `-d'{"cluster":["monitor"], "indices":[{"names":"myapp_*","privileges":["read", "monitor"]}]}'`. Role changes are automatically applied to users.

I still have no idea what the "/main" relates to in the error message but this works.

Comment: Thank you!  There are a dearth of *useful* examples.